# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:filter-invocation-definition-source'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring 3.2.4 application that allows public users (without login) to search in a form. I want to add CSRF Protection to this form, so I add this declaration in my applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">



    <security:http auto-config='true'>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"    />
        <security:csrf/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="anonymousProcessingFilter"    
            class="org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter">
        <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
        <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="filterInvocationInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
            <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
            <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"/>
             <property name="objectDefinitionSource">

        <security:filter-invocation-definition-source>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"  access='ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER'/>              
        </security:filter-invocation-definition-source>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

But I got this error when compiling the project, but of course I don't need any kind of authenticationManager since there is no authenticated users in the application

```
   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 43; columnNumber: 52; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:filter-invocation-definition-source'.:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:filter-invocation-definition-source'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">



    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logoutSuccess*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/main.css" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" 
                             login-processing-url="/loginProcess" 
                             default-target-url="/index.jsp" 
                             authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccess.html" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider >
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```